# JPA navigate unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have an unidirectional relationship. Here i have Employee and Andress entities. In Employee entity i have the following code:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOME_ADDRESS")
private Address homeAddress;
```

What is the correct way to find the Employee entity when i have only the Adress entity. Can I only do that via jpql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this if you have, for example, the id of the address

```
select e from Employee e where e.homeAddress.id = :addressId
```

Using Hibernate criteria API, it would look like this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.createAlias("homeAddress", "homeAddress");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("homeAddress.id", addressId);
Employee employee = (Employee)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks, I know the id, but can I make this without using jpql?

Comment: Oh, I misread the question, I thought you were asking for JPQL solution. I've edited my answer with Hibernate criteria API example. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I didint know of any way to do this without jpql, thanks for introducing Criteria api :) But the jpql solution seems more simple so i'll use it. 
Maybe you can answer my next question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208794/jpa-lookups-with-arrays